# Word index in string

Tags: bash

I want to find the index of a word in a sentence (in my case it is a list of args)

```
...
elif [[ "$#" -gt "0" ]]
then
    ALL_ARGS="$@"
    echo ${ALL_ARGS} | grep -b -o target | sed 's/:.*$//'
    # 14
    TARGET_INDEX=`${ALL_ARGS} | grep -b -o target | sed 's/:.*$//'`
    # error
    # forganize.sh: line 45: .: -n: invalid option
    # .: usage: . filename [arguments]

    echo $TARGET_INDEX
...
```

It works in echo but I can't assign it to a variable.

Also if there is any other way to find index please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `echo` in your line.

```
TARGET_INDEX=$(echo ${ALL_ARGS} | grep -b -o target | sed 's/:.*$//')
```

> Also if there is any other way to find index please let me know.

Do not use upper case variables. Prefer lower case variables in your scripts.

Check your script with http://shellcheck.net

Quote variable expansions. Never `$var` always `"$var"`. [bashfaq quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

`var="$@"` is equal to `var="$*"` - the result of `$@` is joined using the first character in `IFS`. No idea if that is the intention - find the byte offset in arguments joined by spaces.

In bash you may `<<<"$var"` instead of `echo "$var" |` to save one process. Also, use `printf` instead of `echo`. See [why is printf better then echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Do not use ` backticks. Use `$(...)` instead. See [bash hackers obsolete](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

I think `cut` would be simpler then `sed` here, I would:

```
target_index=$(<<<"$*" grep -bo target | cut -d: -f1)
```